# Fix the 'pause' bug in stopwatch

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a very simple stopwatch, but I cannot make 'pause' works properly.
It should pause the stopwatch and after clicking 'START' again - proceed the timer. But it just stopps and resets the timer

```js
var body = document.body;

var start = document.querySelector('.start');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
var reset = document.querySelector('.reset');
var lap = document.querySelector('.lap');

var lapContainer = document.querySelector('.lapContainer');

var mil = document.querySelector('.milis');
var sec = document.querySelector('.secs');
var min = document.querySelector('.mins');
var hours = document.querySelector('.hours');
var flag = false;


// Create blocks for time markers
function createTimeSection(timeType) { // timeType = min/sec/ms/ :
  var lapTime = document.createElement('div');
  lapTime.classList.add('lapSection');
  lapBlock.appendChild(lapTime);
  lapTime.innerHTML = (timeType);
}

function createTimeBlock(type) {
  lapBlock = document.createElement('div');
  lapBlock.classList.add('lapBlock');
  lapContainer.appendChild(lapBlock);
  var lapText = document.createElement('div');

  lapText.classList.add('lapText');
  lapBlock.appendChild(lapText);
  lapText.innerHTML = (type);

  createTimeSection(hours);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(minutes);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(seconds);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(milliseconds);
}

// hide/display START/STOP buttons
function displayStopButton() {
  start.style.display = 'none';
  stop.style.display = 'block';
}

function displayStartButton() {
  start.style.display = 'block';
  stop.style.display = 'none';
}


// Get Date start point
function startStopwatch() {
  flag = true;
  initialDate = new Date;
}


// calculate timer
function getTime() {

  var currentDate = new Date;
  timer = new Date (currentDate - initialDate);
  
  milliseconds = timer.getMilliseconds();
  seconds = timer.getSeconds();
  minutes = timer.getMinutes();
  hours = timer.getUTCHours();

  if(milliseconds < 100){
    milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
  }
  if(seconds < 10){
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  if (hours < 10){
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }
}

// display timer in document
function counter() {
  getTime();
  mil.innerHTML = milliseconds;
  sec.innerHTML = seconds;
  min.innerHTML = minutes;
  hours.innerHTML = hours;
}

// interval for display
function displayTimer() {
  timerId = setInterval(counter, 10);
}


function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  getTime();
  createTimeBlock('STOP');
  flag = false;
}

function newLap() {
  if (flag == true){
    getTime();
    createTimeBlock('LAP');
  } else {
    lapBlock = document.createElement('div');
    lapBlock.classList.add('lapBlock');
    lapContainer.appendChild(lapBlock);
    var lapText = document.createElement('div');

    lapText.classList.add('lapText');
    lapBlock.appendChild(lapText);
    lapText.innerHTML = ('PRESS START FIRST');
  }
}


function resetTimer() {
  flag = false;
  clearInterval(timerId);
  start.style.display = 'block';
  stop.style.display = 'none';
  mil.innerHTML = '00';
  min.innerHTML = '00';
  sec.innerHTML = '00';
  document.querySelector('.lapContainer').innerHTML = '';
}

start.addEventListener('click', startStopwatch);
start.addEventListener('click', displayStopButton);
start.addEventListener('click', displayTimer);

lap.addEventListener('click', newLap)

stop.addEventListener('click', stopTimer)
stop.addEventListener('click', displayStartButton);

reset.addEventListener('click', resetTimer);
```

```css
.top-block{
 position: fixed;
 left: 150px;
}

.sw{
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.buttons-block{
 clear: both;
}

.button{
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}


.start{
 background: green;
 clear: both; 
}

.stop{
 display: none;
 background: yellow;
}

.reset{
 background: #6b919c;
}

.lap{
 background: rgb(120,120,120);
}

.hours,
.secs,
.mins,
.milis{
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 32px;
}

.lapBlock{
 clear: both;
 height: 30px;
 width: 280px;
}

.lapSection{
 float: left;
 margin: 1px;
}

.lapText{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.lapContainer{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="top-block">
  <div class="sw">
    <p class="hours">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="mins">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="secs">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="milis">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons-block">
   <a href="#" class="button start">START</a>
   <a href="#" class="button stop">PAUSE</a>
   <a href="#" class="button lap">LAP</a>
   <a href="#" class="button reset">RESET</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lapContainer">
  
 </div>
```

Or codepen:
http://codepen.io/ArkadiyS/pen/XKdLqz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset date only upon reset of the timer, but you also do it once the timer is paused.

To do this, I've moved the date initialization to the beginning and also applied it on reset.

Also, your timer was continuing to tick even if stopped, to avoid this I'm just counting stop offset and applying it to the date:

```
setInterval(function(){
  if(flag==false) offset+=10;
},10)
```

---

```js
initialDate = new Date;
var body = document.body;

var start = document.querySelector('.start');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
var reset = document.querySelector('.reset');
var lap = document.querySelector('.lap');

var lapContainer = document.querySelector('.lapContainer');

var mil = document.querySelector('.milis');
var sec = document.querySelector('.secs');
var min = document.querySelector('.mins');
var hours = document.querySelector('.hours');
var flag = false;
var waitTimer, offset=0;


// Create blocks for time markers
function createTimeSection(timeType) { // timeType = min/sec/ms/ :
  var lapTime = document.createElement('div');
  lapTime.classList.add('lapSection');
  lapBlock.appendChild(lapTime);
  lapTime.innerHTML = (timeType);
}

function createTimeBlock(type) {
  lapBlock = document.createElement('div');
  lapBlock.classList.add('lapBlock');
  lapContainer.appendChild(lapBlock);
  var lapText = document.createElement('div');

  lapText.classList.add('lapText');
  lapBlock.appendChild(lapText);
  lapText.innerHTML = (type);

  createTimeSection(hours);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(minutes);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(seconds);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(milliseconds);
}

// hide/display START/STOP buttons
function displayStopButton() {
  start.style.display = 'none';
  stop.style.display = 'block';
}

function displayStartButton() {
  start.style.display = 'block';
  stop.style.display = 'none';
}


// Get Date start point
function startStopwatch() {
  flag = true;
  
}
setInterval(function(){
  if(flag==false) offset+=10;
},10)
// calculate timer
function getTime() {

  var currentDate = new Date;
  timer = new Date (currentDate - initialDate - offset);
  
  milliseconds = timer.getMilliseconds();
  seconds = timer.getSeconds();
  minutes = timer.getMinutes();
  hours = timer.getUTCHours();

  if(milliseconds < 100){
    milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
  }
  if(seconds < 10){
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  if (hours < 10){
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }
}

// display timer in document
function counter() {
  getTime();
  mil.innerHTML = milliseconds;
  sec.innerHTML = seconds;
  min.innerHTML = minutes;
  hours.innerHTML = hours;
}

// interval for display
function displayTimer() {
  timerId = setInterval(counter, 10);
}


function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  getTime();
  createTimeBlock('STOP');
  flag = false;
}

function newLap() {
  if (flag == true){
    getTime();
    createTimeBlock('LAP');
  } else {
    lapBlock = document.createElement('div');
    lapBlock.classList.add('lapBlock');
    lapContainer.appendChild(lapBlock);
    var lapText = document.createElement('div');

    lapText.classList.add('lapText');
    lapBlock.appendChild(lapText);
    lapText.innerHTML = ('PRESS START FIRST');
  }
}


function resetTimer() {
  initialDate = new Date;
  flag = false;
  offset=0;
  clearInterval(timerId);
  start.style.display = 'block';
  stop.style.display = 'none';
  mil.innerHTML = '00';
  min.innerHTML = '00';
  sec.innerHTML = '00';
  document.querySelector('.lapContainer').innerHTML = '';
}

start.addEventListener('click', startStopwatch);
start.addEventListener('click', displayStopButton);
start.addEventListener('click', displayTimer);

lap.addEventListener('click', newLap)

stop.addEventListener('click', stopTimer)
stop.addEventListener('click', displayStartButton);

reset.addEventListener('click', resetTimer);
```

```css
.top-block{
 position: fixed;
 left: 150px;
}

.sw{
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.buttons-block{
 clear: both;
}

.button{
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}


.start{
 background: green;
 clear: both; 
}

.stop{
 display: none;
 background: yellow;
}

.reset{
 background: #6b919c;
}

.lap{
 background: rgb(120,120,120);
}

.hours,
.secs,
.mins,
.milis{
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 32px;
}

.lapBlock{
 clear: both;
 height: 30px;
 width: 280px;
}

.lapSection{
 float: left;
 margin: 1px;
}

.lapText{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.lapContainer{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-block">
  <div class="sw">
    <p class="hours">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="mins">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="secs">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="milis">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons-block">
   <a href="#" class="button start">START</a>
   <a href="#" class="button stop">PAUSE</a>
   <a href="#" class="button lap">LAP</a>
   <a href="#" class="button reset">RESET</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lapContainer">
  
 </div>
```

Comment: When you click Start the first time, this times from when you opened the page.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I did it there initially, but then removed for some reason. Now working :)

Comment: @nicael, well it's still doesn't work. Now it starts the count once script is loaded, or 'reset' clicked.

Comment: @Ark Indeed, I'll fix it soon.

Comment: @Ark It's fixed, though I have a weird definition of "soon" :D

Comment: @Ark Please accept then - just click the checkmark below the score of my answer so as it becomes green.

Comment: @nicael, done! And sorry but I cannot vote for it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish the first click on `Start`, which should start counting from 0, with subsequent clicks. You can use a variable that's set by the `Reset` button. In my code this is the `first_time` variable.

When you pause the stopwatch, you need to save the current time. Then when you restart it, adjust `initialDate` by the difference in time since it was paused.

```
// Get Date start point
function startStopwatch() {
  flag = true;
  if (first_time) {
    initialDate = new Date;
    first_time = false;
  } else {
    initialDate.setMilliseconds(initialDate.getMilliseconds() + (new Date - pauseTime));
  }
}
```

```js
var body = document.body;

var start = document.querySelector('.start');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stop');
var reset = document.querySelector('.reset');
var lap = document.querySelector('.lap');

var lapContainer = document.querySelector('.lapContainer');

var mil = document.querySelector('.milis');
var sec = document.querySelector('.secs');
var min = document.querySelector('.mins');
var hours = document.querySelector('.hours');
var flag = false;
var first_time = true;

// Create blocks for time markers
function createTimeSection(timeType) { // timeType = min/sec/ms/ :
  var lapTime = document.createElement('div');
  lapTime.classList.add('lapSection');
  lapBlock.appendChild(lapTime);
  lapTime.innerHTML = (timeType);
}

function createTimeBlock(type) {
  lapBlock = document.createElement('div');
  lapBlock.classList.add('lapBlock');
  lapContainer.appendChild(lapBlock);
  var lapText = document.createElement('div');

  lapText.classList.add('lapText');
  lapBlock.appendChild(lapText);
  lapText.innerHTML = (type);

  createTimeSection(hours);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(minutes);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(seconds);
  createTimeSection(':');
  createTimeSection(milliseconds);
}

// hide/display START/STOP buttons
function displayStopButton() {
  start.style.display = 'none';
  stop.style.display = 'block';
}

function displayStartButton() {
  start.style.display = 'block';
  stop.style.display = 'none';
}


// Get Date start point
function startStopwatch() {
  flag = true;
  if (first_time) {
    initialDate = new Date;
    first_time = false;
  } else {
    initialDate.setMilliseconds(initialDate.getMilliseconds() + (new Date - pauseTime));
  }
}  


// calculate timer
function getTime() {

  var currentDate = new Date;
  timer = new Date (currentDate - initialDate);
  
  milliseconds = timer.getMilliseconds();
  seconds = timer.getSeconds();
  minutes = timer.getMinutes();
  hours = timer.getUTCHours();

  if(milliseconds < 100){
    milliseconds = '0' + milliseconds;
  }
  if(seconds < 10){
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  if (hours < 10){
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }
}

// display timer in document
function counter() {
  getTime();
  mil.innerHTML = milliseconds;
  sec.innerHTML = seconds;
  min.innerHTML = minutes;
  hours.innerHTML = hours;
}

// interval for display
function displayTimer() {
  timerId = setInterval(counter, 10);
}


function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  getTime();
  createTimeBlock('STOP');
  flag = false;
  pauseTime = new Date;
}

function newLap() {
  if (flag == true){
    getTime();
    createTimeBlock('LAP');
  } else {
    lapBlock = document.createElement('div');
    lapBlock.classList.add('lapBlock');
    lapContainer.appendChild(lapBlock);
    var lapText = document.createElement('div');

    lapText.classList.add('lapText');
    lapBlock.appendChild(lapText);
    lapText.innerHTML = ('PRESS START FIRST');
  }
}


function resetTimer() {
  flag = false;
  first_time = true;
  clearInterval(timerId);
  start.style.display = 'block';
  stop.style.display = 'none';
  mil.innerHTML = '00';
  min.innerHTML = '00';
  sec.innerHTML = '00';
  document.querySelector('.lapContainer').innerHTML = '';
}

start.addEventListener('click', startStopwatch);
start.addEventListener('click', displayStopButton);
start.addEventListener('click', displayTimer);

lap.addEventListener('click', newLap)

stop.addEventListener('click', stopTimer)
stop.addEventListener('click', displayStartButton);

reset.addEventListener('click', resetTimer);
```

```css
.top-block{
 position: fixed;
 left: 150px;
}

.sw{
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 margin: 10px;
 text-align: center;
}

.buttons-block{
 clear: both;
}

.button{
 margin: 10px;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 color: black;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}


.start{
 background: green;
 clear: both; 
}

.stop{
 display: none;
 background: yellow;
}

.reset{
 background: #6b919c;
}

.lap{
 background: rgb(120,120,120);
}

.hours,
.secs,
.mins,
.milis{
 margin: 0;
 line-height: 32px;
}

.lapBlock{
 clear: both;
 height: 30px;
 width: 280px;
}

.lapSection{
 float: left;
 margin: 1px;
}

.lapText{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5px;
}

.lapContainer{
 float: left;
 margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-block">
  <div class="sw">
    <p class="hours">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="mins">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="secs">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sw">
    <p class="milis">00</p>
  </div>

  <div class="buttons-block">
   <a href="#" class="button start">START</a>
   <a href="#" class="button stop">PAUSE</a>
   <a href="#" class="button lap">LAP</a>
   <a href="#" class="button reset">RESET</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lapContainer">
  
 </div>
```

Another option would be to have separate `Start` and `Resume` buttons. The `Start` button would initialize `initialDate`, but the `Resume` button wouldn't. 
Clicking the `Pause` button shows the `Resume` button, while clicking `Reset` shows the `Start` button.

Comment: it doesn't stop counting, once 'pause' clicked. Timer isn't showed on screen, but after you click 'start' again it jumps forward

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted to do. But now that I think about it, that's closer to what the Lap button does.

Comment: What you need to do is adjust the start time by the amount of time you've been paused. I don't have time to code this right now.

Comment: Works ok now. Thanks a lot!